# Python: Is there any method to check whether target window is topmost or not?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making mouse,keyboard macro program using python. The program consists of a button that opens a window for writing macros, and a button that executes a macro. I put hotkey to execute macro conveniently...but there was a mistake. When i write a macro in a new window, it automatically runs when a hotkey is pressed. so i am trying to put condition code, but it's not working.. :(

Here is my code summary.

```
root.Tk()
root.title("Fine Macro ver1.0")

#there are some widgets, but i've omitted them

global btncdt
btncdt = 1                 # Declaring global variable (which is btncdt) to limit hotkey

def key():
    keyWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    keyWindow.geometry("300x260+300+200")
    keyLabel = Label(keyWindow, text='키보드 입력내용을 설정하세요')
    keyText = Text(keyWindow, width=35, height=10 )
    global btncdt
    btncdt = btncdt * 0

def setKey():
    keyvalue = keyText.get(1.0,END).rstrip()
    putKey(keyvalue)
    global btncdt                
    btncdt = btncdt + 1
    print(btncdt)
    keyWindow.destroy()
keyConfirm = Button(keyWindow,width=4, height=1 ,text="confirm", command=setKey )
keyLabel.pack(side=TOP , pady=10)
keyText.pack(side=TOP, pady =5)
keyConfirm.pack(side=TOP, pady=10)

def doStart():
#there are some macrocodes. 

def hotkey():
    global btncdt
if btncdt > 0:
    keyboard.on_press_key("S", doStart)

hotkey()
root.mainloop()
```

please help...:(

Comment: do You want to check for focus? `root.get_focus()`? otherwise what did You expect a macro to do? not run if called? also do You know what `-topmost` attribute does? it just places the window on top of others at all times so even if it is out of focus it is still in front of other windows